# in ten minutes vs within ten minutes

Tags: meaning, prepositions

> The machine will start automatically **in** ten minutes.
>
> The machine will start automatically **within** ten minutes.

What's the difference between the two sentences?

Comment: Essentially, if it *starts **in** ten minutes* the implication is it will start *exactly* ten minutes from time of utterance. Replacing this with ***within*** means it will start ***at any time** between "now" and ten minutes later than time of utterance*.

Answer (score 4):

If someone says;

> The machine will start automatically ***in ten minutes.***

It is pretty self explanatory, they are saying an exact time that the machine will start.

But if they say;

> The machine will start automatically ***within ten minutes***.

Then they are just saying any time *less than* **or equal to**  ten minutes.

If someone says the first sentence they are saying in ten minutes from now the machine will start. If someone says the second sentence they are saying in some time less than ten minutes the machine will start.

Comment: Less than or equal to, I would say – not strictly less than.

Comment: Yeah I guess that is more correct. @J.R.

Comment: Can I say 'ten minutes later' instead of 'in ten minutes?

Comment: @AbuNaimMuhammedKalil. "ten minutes later" would be ten minutes after some other specified event, not ten minutes from now. For example, you could say "I will switch on the power after lunch. The machine will start automatically ten minutes later". That means the machine will start ten minutes after the power goes on, not ten minutes from now.